# Android App connecting to REST Service - Connection Refused

Tags: android, api, http, rest

I am developing an Android app that involves calls to a RESTful API. I have the REST service written in Python, running on my laptop (`192.168.156.1`) on port 8080. I have my phone tethered to my laptop with a Connectify Wifi connection. The phone is at `192.168.156.112`. Now, I can access the service from the phone's browser with a URL such as `http://192.168.156.1:8080/lighting/12345`. However, when I try to access it from the app, i get a 'Connection Refused' error in LogCat. The following is the code i'm using to make the connection.

```
    String sampleURL = "`http://192.168.156.1:8080/lighting/weert`";
        HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         try
         {
             HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(sampleURL);
             String serverString = "";
             HttpResponse response= Client.execute(httpget);
             StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
             if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                 ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                 response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                 out.close();
                 serverString = out.toString();
             } 
             threadMsg(SetServerString);
          }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e("RESTCALL",ex.getMessage());  
            threadMsg("Fail!");
         }
```

threadMsg() is the method that passes the response string back to the UI thread.

Any help resolving this issue would be great! Thanks in advance!

Update: Adding Stack Trace

```
    I/ActivityManager(  246): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=   [android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.testreceiver/.MainActivity u=0} from pid 464
    I/ActivityManager(  246): Displayed com.example.testreceiver/.MainActivity: +315ms
    W/System.err(15799): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.156.1:8080 refused
    D/AudioHardware(   89): AudioHardware pcm playback is going to standby.
    D/AudioHardware(   89): closePcmOut_l() mPcmOpenCnt: 1
    W/System.err(15799):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
    W/System.err(15799):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    W/System.err(15799):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    W/System.err(15799):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
    W/System.err(15799):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
    W/System.err(15799):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
    W/System.err(15799):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465) 
    W/System.err(15799):    at com.example.testreceiver.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:47)
    W/System.err(15799):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 
    W/System.err(15799): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.156.1 (port 8080): connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
    W/System.err(15799):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
    W/System.err(15799):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
    W/System.err(15799):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
    W/System.err(15799):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
    W/System.err(15799):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
    W/System.err(15799):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
    W/System.err(15799):    ... 8 more
    W/System.err(15799): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
    W/System.err(15799):    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
    W/System.err(15799):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
    W/System.err(15799):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
    W/System.err(15799):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
    W/System.err(15799):    ... 13 more
    E/RESTCALL(15799): Connection to `http://192.168.156.1:8080` refused
```

Also, here is the code that's running on the server.

```
    import socket
    from bottle import route, run@route('/lighting/<name>', method='GET')

    def hello(name="ABC"):
    return name

    run(host='192.168.156.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: Mmmm... I don't know if its a matter of permissions. Do you use anroid.permission.INTERNET?

Comment: Yes, I have that in my manifest. Could it be something to do with HTTP header(s) that I'm not adding?

Comment: Is you're pc firewall allowing port 8080?

Comment: The firewall's turned off.

Comment: could you add all the stack trace of the exception updating your post?

Comment: What's running on your server? You're not setting any headers for you request. Perhaps your server code is strict about content-type and other header values and it rejects a request if those are not set properly.

Comment: I've just added the stack trace.

Comment: @Ameen I've added the code that's running on the server in the original question. It's very basic for now.

Comment: "Connection refused" implies there's nothing listening on the port i.e. server not running. Your logcat shows "Host unreachable" which means that the host itself cannot be routed to - are you sure the device is in the same (non-routable 192.168) network as the server? (Also why there are backticks in the URL?)

Comment: The phone and the laptop running the server are both on the same WiFi network. I can access the service from the phone's browser too. Also, the backticks were just me trying to beat StackOverflow's URL checking grammar. :/ They weren't part of the original code.

Comment: Any suggestions, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! I stopped using the connectify hotspot and switched to a router, which my phone and laptop are connected to now.

Comment: I have same  problem, can you explain more how you switched to a router?